# Usage of am/pm with the past/to format

Tags: time

Which of the following sentences is more common? Are they both acceptable?

*It's twenty-five past seven am.*

*It's seven twenty-five am.*

I wonder if the usage of *am/pm* is okay when using the *past/to* format to tell the time.

A native person would be more likely to say:

7:25 am -> *Seven twenty-five am.* / *Twenty-five past seven am.*

7:47 am -> *Seven forty-seven am.* / *Thirteen to eight am.*

Comment: Both are common and acceptable. I often hear the first on the radio, but that's not an exclusive use. You could even say "It's thirty-five (to/until) eight am."

Comment: Personally, I don't much like ***am*** tacked on the end in the first example. I'd only use it myself if the ***am/pm*** distinction were effectively either an "afterthought" (to resolve an ambiguity just noticed while I was speaking), or as an "intensifier" (emphasizing that although it might be an "ordinary" time in the evening, it's ***very early*** in the ***morning***). So in either case I might *write* it preceded by a dash (and possibly followed by an exclamation mark! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I agree. In Britain it is very rare to use am/pm with the *to/past* form.

Comment: @WS2 Would you say, then, that the most common way for somebody who wants to specify what part of the they they are referring to when telling the time is the _hour + minutes_ format, such as _Seven twenty-five am._ instead of _Twenty-five past seven am._ Does the latter sound odd to your native ears? Thanks

Comment: @TMuskett  Yes, very unusual.

Comment: Using to/past (or the incredibly confusing "of") is a cultural thing -- each culture has a slightly different way of doing it (some not so slight).  Tacking on am/pm would be understood but is probably not idiomatic to most people.  In fact, even specifying the hour is unusual for some cultures.

Comment: (And if am/pm were to be specified it wouldn't be "twenty-five past seven am" but rather "twenty-five past seven in the morning".)

Answer (score 1):

As a native speaker, I would never say twenty-five pas seven am nor would I say thirteen to eight am.  I personally only use this structure informally and only to reference the present time. I would rely on the fact that the person I'm speaking with knows generally whether is is before or after noon.  If I need to be specific about whether the time is day or night then I format it as seven twenty-five am.

Comment: Personally, I'd never say *thirteen to eight* anyway - I often omit the word ***minutes*** after any number divisible by 5, but not otherwise (except after *quarter*, obviously). But I don't recognize your point about "only to reference the present time". Are you saying you're fine with *It's [now] ten to six*, but that you have a problem with *You need to get up tomorrow at ten to six*? That strikes me as a very odd restriction.